# Are 4-vectors covariant under general coordinate transformations?

Tags: general-relativity, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus, vectors, covariance

In the context of special relativity, it is well known that 4-vectors are covariant under Lorentz transformations (which is a linear transformation in space-time), however are they covariant under general coordinate transformations (GCT)? Personally, I don't see why they shouldn't be. I mean in GR, when we refer to 4-vectors (or in general, tensors) we are talking about coordinate-free objects that are invariant under all coordinate transformations not just linear ones; so why the sudden emphasis on linear transformations in SR if the 4-vectors are invariant under GCT? Rarely do I see a textbook that touches upon non-Lorentzian transformations in SR, which strikes me as odd.

This also raises another question: If 4-vectors are indeed covariant under GCT then the relativistic Newton's 2nd law $F=mA$ (where $F$ is the 4-force and $A$ is the 4-acceleration) should also be covariant under GCT, and in particular, valid in non-inertial frames given that it's an equality between coordinate-free objects. Am i correct?

Comment: 4-vectors are not invariant even under Lorentz transformations. They are "covariant", only (Lorentz) scalars such as the Minkowski norm are invariant.

Comment: Under a coordinate transformation, the basis transforms covariantly while the components transform contravariantly (in some sense inversely to the basis) to create the "invariant" object known as a 4-vector (which has constant magnitude/norm and direction). This is what I meant by invariance and that's how I learned it at least. As far as i can tell, some people use invariance and others use covariance to describe that. Am i wrong regarding that? Either way, you can reformulate my question by replacing invariance with covariance and my question would still hold.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your terminology, but it seems like this is trivially not so. Take any vector in flat space that's away from the origin in some coordinate system of your choosing. Now transform coordinates by shifting the original vector to the origin of the new system.

Comment: What you're essentially describing is parallel transporting a vector no? This doesn't change the norm of the vector and it doesn't change its direction (otherwise your space would not be flat). When i was learning GR, there was constant emphasis on the fact that 4-vectors and tensors are "static"  (invariant/covariant) objects, which is a big part why they are so useful, they have predictable behavior. When you transform your coordinates, you know exactly how the basis transforms, and hence you would know how components transform (they have to transform in a way to keep this object "static")

Comment: Furthermore, there is a difference between GCT's (which are just changes of coordinates) and symmetries (which have a physical action). I think this is part of your confusion.